# Arithmetic's in an update statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I really can't wrap my head around this update sql statement.

I have the following schema for a copy table and a rental table :

**copy** (
  copy_id ,
  movie_id ,
  branch_id ,
  primary key (copy_id));

**rental** (
  customer_id,
  copy_id  ,
  outdate ,
  returndate ,
  primary key (customer_id,copy_id,outdate));

There will be multiple copies of the same movie. for a single movie_id, we can have multiple copy_id.
Each copy of a movie has a globally unique copy_id. So copies of 2 different movies cannot have the same copy_id.

There are multiple branches that have a copy of the movie, and certainly the copy_id will be unique.

The same movie and copy will definitely appear in rented multiple times, if it has been rented more than once.

I need to write a update statement such that - say we have 10 copies of a movie at a branch, and a time span of 30 days, so out of 300 rental days(30 days * 10 copies) the copies need to be rented out for at least 290 rental days. If this is true then I need to add another copy of that particular movie at that branch.

I tried to explain the problem in the best possible way I could. In short, I need to add a copy if the movie is rented out 90% of the time at a branch.

Comment: Presuming `outdate` is something like a timestamp (and not, as the name states, a date), and you should remove `customer_id` from the primary key, as it's actually dependent information.  For the span of 30 days, how are `outdate` and `returndate` related?  Even if you can't check a movie out for that long, you're going to have some crossing the boundary.  What are you getting stuck on in your statement?  You should be able to `SUM(returnDate - outdate`) or something.

Comment: For a particular copy, I can have a customer take the movie out for 30 whole days. So if i have ten customers who take a movie out from a branch for 30 days, then you can conclude that the movie was rented out 100% of the time. I don't really think customer_id is of any concern here in this particular statement, so we can leave it aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select branch_id, movie_id, count(*) from copy group by branch_id, movie_id

> this query is branchs movie count. maybe you already have branch table, use that.

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(outdate, '%Y%m'),branch_id, movie_id, SUM(DATEDIFF(returndate , outdate)) FROM copy AS c INNER JOIN rental AS r ON c.copy_id = r.copy_id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(outdate, '%Y%m'),c.branch_id, c.movie_id

> this query is monthly rental time per branch and movie.

that query is basic query for calculate. and you can make logic like

if monthly rental time + new rental time > branchs rental limit

(
 add new copy request
)